# Como crio a variável que salve todas essas informações e depois mostre no console.log()?

Tags: javascript

Crie uma função que dado o objeto a seguir:

```
var endereco = {
 rua: "Rua dos pinheiros",
 numero: 1293,
 bairro: "Centro",
 cidade: "São Paulo",
 uf: "SP"
};
```

Retorne o seguinte conteúdo:

O usuário mora em São Paulo / SP, no bairro Centro, na rua "Rua dos Pinheiros" com
nº 1293.

Fiz assim, mas não está certo:

```
    <script>
        var endereco = {
            rua: 'dos Pinheiros',
            num: 1293,
            bairro: 'Centro',
            cidade: 'São Paulo',
            uf: 'SP'
        };

        function paraString(endereco) {
            return 'O usuário mora em' ${endereco.cidade} '/' ${endereco.uf}', no bairro' ${endereco.bairo}', na rua' ${endereco.rua} 'com nº' ${endereco.num}.
        };

        console.log(paraString(endereco));

    </script>
```

Comment: É pq vc utilizou **aspas simples** quando deveria utilizar crase **``**

Comment: valew! Era isso msm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

No JavaScript, quando você vai usar o ${variable}, você está falando de `template strings`, que começa e termina com ` (crase).

Fiz uma modificação no seu código (e arrumei algumas coisas, como trocar `bairo` para `bairro` no método), o jeito correto é esse:

```
var endereco = {
   rua: "dos Pinheiros",
   num: 1293,
   bairro: "Centro",
   cidade: "São Paulo",
   uf: "SP"
};

function paraString(endereco) {
   return `O usuário mora em ${endereco.cidade}/${endereco.uf}, no bairro ${endereco.bairro}, na rua ${endereco.rua} com nº ${endereco.num}.`;
}

console.log(paraString(endereco));
```

Answer (score 2):

Coloquei em uma variavel para ver se está pegando corretamente os endereços
E tinha mais um erro onde você estava utilizando aspas simnples é aspas duplas

```
<script>
        var endereco = {
            rua: 'dos Pinheiros',
            num: 1293,
            bairro: 'Centro',
            cidade: 'São Paulo',
            uf: 'SP'
        };

        function paraString(endereco) {
            var string = "O usuário mora em" + endereco.cidade +  "/ "+ endereco.uf + ", no bairro " + endereco.bairro + ", na rua" + endereco.rua + " com nº " + endereco.num;
            return string;
        };

        console.log(paraString(endereco));

    </script>
```

Comment: Valew, é isso msm! Muito obrigado man.